# How to change tab icon in Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, favicon

[image: Tab Icon]

How and where can I change it in Spring MVC project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `favicon.ico` in the root of your webapp (the webapp folder, like [this](https://github.com/david99world/ESPNPlayerViewer/tree/master/FootieViewer/src/main/webapp)).

Out of habit in SpringMVC, I also put the following mapping.

```
<mvc:resources location="/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/directory/to/filename.png">` to your .jsp file. Like so:

[image]

Here's the directory where tab_icon.png is located:

[image]